# Spring Boot BOM for non boot spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-bom

I'd like to use spring boot specific BOM for my non-boot spring project. Is it acceptable to include **spring-boot-dependencies** or **platform-bom** and what's better?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

or

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid approaches.

To quote the [Spring IO Platform documentation](https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Brussels-SR5/reference/htmlsingle/) :

> Spring IO Platform builds on top of Spring Boot

So, they provide what you search for a non spring boot application : a set of consistent dependencies and some specific beans provided by Spring Boot.

Now, personally, I would chose `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies` as Spring Boot is mature, have an important and active community and is often updated.
See the [spring-boot github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot).
It is not the case of the [spring-io/platform](https://github.com/spring-io/platform).